# ExtractTextPlugin doesn't work with Angular AOT build

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular2-aot, extract-text-plugin

So I am trying to create a Angular (`4.4.4`) Webpack (`3.6.0`) starter with AOT build and I am running into an issue with extracting the css into a seperate bundle (using extract-text-webpack-plugin `3.0.1`).

When I run my prod build the webpack build gets stuck at `95% emitting`. It never goes to 100% and it never outputs the dist bundle. At first I tried to create inline CSS with the `style-loader` (`0.19.0`), but that wasn't a success since Angular AOT build has no window object during the build (sass-loader will fail on this point). Due to this I am forced to extract the css into a seperate bundle during production (not a bad thing at all).

But somehow the compiler stalls and never gives an error.

**webpack.common.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main.ts',
        vendor: getVendorPackages()
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "website.bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin( //Resolve Angular warnings
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
        ),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ //Create secondary bundle containing dependencies
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
            minChunks(module) {
                const context = module.context;
                return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
            },
        }),
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({ //Generate index.html
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin( //Only export the locals we need | https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2517
            /moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en|nl/
        )
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.scss']
    }
};
```

**Webpack.prod.js**

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ // Fallback is not necessary, since style-loader will fail with AOT build
                    use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // Uglyfy the JavaScript output
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: true
            },
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            comments: false
        }),
        new AotPlugin({ // Create AOT build
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
            entryModule: __dirname + '/src/app/app.module#AppModule'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // Set the node env so that the project knows what to enable or disable
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css") //Create an external style bundle
    ]
});
```

---

For the prod build I am running the following npm task: `"build --prod": "webpack -p --config webpack.prod.js --progress"`

And my **package.json dependencies** looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.4",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.7.2",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.43",
    "@types/node": "8.0.31",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.3",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.3",
    "webpack": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0"
  }
```

My **Angular component** is as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hn-root',
    templateUrl: './app.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

And my **project structure** is:

```
- src
  -- app
     -- app.component.ts
     -- app.html
     -- app.module.ts
     -- app.scss
  index.html
  main.ts
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a bit more about view encapsulation in Angular I now know that you shouldn't use style-loader with Angular.

`Style-loader` is nice if you want to have global styles, but when you want to have styles that are only applied to the component where they are included then you should use `raw-loader` instead.

So after adding the raw-loader (`npm install --save-dev raw-loader`) I changed my **webpack.prod.js** to:

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // Uglyfy the JavaScript output
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: true
            },
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            comments: false
        }),
        new AotPlugin({ // Create AOT build
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
            entryModule: __dirname + '/src/app/app.module#AppModule'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // Set the node env so that the project knows what to enable or disable
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

This way I can use view encapsulation like Angular recommends (this is also how the angular-cli does it).

Sources:

[Github - AngularClass](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/136)

[Github - Angular starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components)